# Drop a Unique Constraint

Tags: sql-server

I need to drop a Unique constraint on a previously existing table and create a new unique constraint that will include extra column. Can I use the name of the constraint to drop it? or will the name of the unique constraint change based on Datasource. I need to execute the script on multiple instances of same DB (eg. dev,test,prod)

Comment: You will need to ensure your constraint name is same across all instances. Otherwise, you will need to run the script `ALTER TABLE yourtable
DROP CONSTRAINT uc_example` replacing the `uc_example` each time you switch your instance while your constraint name differs.

Comment: That depends....did you name the constraint when you created it or not? If you did not name it then the name will be different on every instance.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for all the responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the name of the constraint, provided that you previously deleted and it was a named contraint.

Comment: How do I figure out if it was a named constraint?

Comment: Query the sql system table where constraints are defined and check the name of the contraint

       SELECT * FROM SYSKEYCST WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA,     TABLE_NAME) = 
('SCHEMA', 'TABLE')